# Patterns on apple based (iPhone & iPod) serial numbers?

Tags: iphone, serial-port, ipod

We are currently running an iPhone repair website and are looking into identifying phones and ipods from serial numbers. Has anyone come across a pattern in serial numbers or an API which is already built for this purpose ?

I know that apple already have there service checker but we would like to build somthing into our admin system.

Comment: Are you an Apple Authorized Service Provider? I'd imagine that they provide this sort of info/API to authorized shops.

Comment: How is this "Programming Related"? Try the Apple Stackexchange site instead.

Comment: The reason im asking in stack overflow is that I am searching for a PHP API Solution to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

The pattern is always triplets of letters or numbers. They're never mixed.